# How do i make a "create text/vc channel" command that only members with admin and manage channel permissions can use?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, discord.js

How would I add all this code together? I want a create channel command that only people with admin or manage channel perms can use, and if someone uses the command and they don't have perms then it would show "You do not have permission to use this command" here's the code I want to combine;

````
    message.guild.channels
      .create(name, {
        type: 'text',
      })
------------------------------------------------------
if (
      member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') ||
      member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')
    )
---------------------------------------------------------
message.channel.send(`${tag} That channel has beem created`)
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`${tag} Please specify a name.`)
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send(
        `${tag} You do not have permission to use this command.`
      )
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GuildMember.hasPermission](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission).
Here is an example:

```js
if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the `MANAGE_CHANNELS` permission.');
```

This only works if message is a Message object, or for some reason you put the GuildMember object into an object named `message`.
Also, in JavaScript, whenever you want to stop a function, use `return`, and whenever you want to break a loop, use `break`